# How does BigQuery caching on time partitioned tables work?

Tags: caching, google-bigquery

In contrast with the BigQuery documentation, we see that it **DOES** cache the results when selecting data from a streaming, data partitioned table (**Standard SQL**).

**Example:**
When we perform a *deterministic* date scan on the streaming, data partitioned table using:

`where (_PARTITIONTIME > '2017-11-12'  or _PARTITIONTIME is null)`

...BigQuery caches the data for 5 to 20 minutes if we fire the same exact query within that time frame.

While in my interpretation of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results) it states that it SHOULD NOT cache the data:

*'When any of the tables referenced by the query have recently received streaming inserts (a streaming buffer is attached to the table) even if no new rows have arrived'*

**Important notes:**

- Our test query queries heartbeat events that really arrive at us continuously
- We actually **want** this caching behavior, because we do not always need to have data to be actual to the last second. We just want to know if we really can depend on this behavior.

**Our Questions:**

- What is going on here / Why does the BQ caching happen at all?
- The time this data stays in the BQ cache is 'random' (between 5-20 minutes). What does this mean?

Comment: Since you used streaming table and partitioned table interchangeably in the question, I'm not sure which one you're referring to. Or, you're streaming into a partitioned table and thought caching shouldn't work, but it's working?

Comment: i corrected it. It is a streaming table that is date partitioned too. And yes, according to the documentation caching should NOT work then. 
But apparently it does. Though not for 24 hours, but somewhere between 5-20 minutes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying the question. I think it's an overlook that we didn't disabled caching for partitioned tables with streaming data. It should as otherwise the query might return outdated results.

We invalidate the cache when the table is changed. Streaming into the table will cause the table to be changed. I guess that's why the cache is invalidated between 5 to 20 minutes.

Comment: But it is still weird behaviour, as this is a table where every second new data should arrive. 
AFAIK google does do some micro-batching in Bigquery to add data from the streaming buffer to the persisted table.
But this query IS even selecting data from the streaming buffer (_PARTITIONTIME is null) and still manages to do caching...

Comment: Yes it's weird/wrong behavior. I filed a bug internally. For partitioned tables we don't take streaming buffer into account for caching, but we should. The table is changed when data batched in streaming buffer is written to the table, which invalidates the cache. Thanks for reporting this problem.